# equivalent to {'display': ''} within stylesheet

Tags: javascript, html, css

Within Javascript I am able to make a div (a rectangle with a solid border), set its display to none, and then change its display setting back to showing itself using {'display': ''}

Ex:

```
var overlay = $('<div class="area"></div>')
    .css({position: 'absolute', left: l + 'px',
    top: t + 'px', border: 'solid', borderColor: 'red', display: 'none' }). 

overlay.css({'display': ''}); 
});
```

I want to make a CSS class that sets its elements display's back to their defaults:

```
<style id="default">.default { display: '';}</style>
<div class="default"></div>
```

This does not work. Can anyone tell me the correct syntax for this?

Comment: I assume you mean `display:block` but it's not clear. The default display value of a div is `block` but you may have changed that. Plus you seem to be mixing IDs and classes...so that might be another thing.

Comment: If you set style by javascript, so it is in inline attribute, you can only use display: block !important; to rewrite it. But I can't recommend it to use. Sooner or later, you will hate !important :)
I can recommend you to change classes by javascript and css styles have separated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('a.show').click(function() {
  $('.area').addClass('show');
});
$('a.hide').click(function() {
  $('.area').removeClass('show');
});
```

```css
.area {
  position: absolute;
  left: lpx;
  top: 30px;
  display: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
.area.show {
  display: block;
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="area"></div>
<a class="show">SHOW</a>
<a class="hide">HIDE</a>
```